# Set custom string as non-steam game using Steam API?

Tags: c#, c++, steamworks-api

How can I set a custom string as a non-steam-game status using Steam API?

For example:
I want "Listening to Spotify" to show on my status as a non-steam-game as well as reset its status back to *online*.

Comment: Checking steam [API related to the status](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api/ISteamFriends#FriendGameInfo_t) info, I find that it uses a [game related ID](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api/steam_api#CGameID) so I find very ubnlikely you could do what you want.

Comment: Is that an answer? It looks like you're just talking to yourself.

Comment: It isn't because you can't use Steam and SteamKit2 at same time.

Comment: bardbury9, using SteamKit2 you could do that by setting random gameid and game_extra_info to the string to set the status and to reset just set game_extra_info to nothing and gameid to 0 but you can't use SteamKit2 and Steam at same time. (edited)